# How to remove JAX-WS Web Services node in Eclipse Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, jax-ws

For development I use Eclipse Helios. In one of my projects in the project explorer a new node showed up. It is called JAX-WS Web Services. I do NOT use webservices in my project. The node has two sub nodes, Service Endpoint Interface and Web Services. Both of them are empty. I have some other project open too. They do not show this node.

How can I remove this unwanted JAX-WS Web Services node from my project?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't care about JAX-WS, you can hide it from the Project Explorer. To do this, click the little down arrow button (see image below) and, from the popup menu, choose "Customize View...". On the Customize View dialog, goto the "Content" tab. On the Content tab, uncheck "JAX-WS Web Services Elements".

[image: click the little down arrow button]

Comment: Does hiding it also disable it (for lower resource usage)?

Comment: I'm not really sure. If anyone knows, please comment.

Comment: I'm just wondering why it is showing in some projects only. There must be some kind "JAX WS" nature which I would like to disable in projects that do not (any more) have anything JAX-WS related.

Comment: Since Eclipse 2019-12/4.14 the View Menu's icon is no longer a chevron but [a vertical ellipsis (⋮)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#new-view-menu-icon). Therein it's _Filters and Customization..._ → _Content_ → ☐ _SR-109 Web Services Index_ now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Package Explorer view instead of the Project Explorer view: those nodes don't appear.

Comment: I think Package Explorer is probably what most people should be using :thumb:

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable JAX-RS support on you project, you can do it following this two steps:

First access your project properties

[image]

Then filter properties by JAX-RS, disable JAX-RS support and click on Apply and close

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that if you create your dynamic web project with eclipse, you can not remove JAX-WS, unless you create your project in other ways.