# JSR-109 Web Services remove in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsr

In Eclipse's *Project Explorer* view there is a project named "*JSR-109 Web Services*" that can not be deleted or removed.

I did not create this project. It came to Project Explorer by itself.

How do I remove this "*JSR-109 Web Services*"?

Answer (score 22):

Select "*Customize View...*" on the Project Explorer view's menu (on the view's upper-right upside-down triangule button).

Select the "*Content*" tab and uncheck "*JSR-109 Web Services Index*".

Comment: Since Eclipse 2019-12/4.14 the View Menu's icon is no longer a chevron but [a vertical ellipsis (⋮)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#new-view-menu-icon). Therein it's _Filters and Customization..._ → _Content_ → ☐ _SR-109 Web Services Index_ now.

Comment: In 2022-03 eclipse for mac, click on the funnel (filters) which is on top-right of the project explorer. Then in "Contents" tab, uncheck the (last) item "JSR-109 Web Services Index".

Answer (score 9):

Delete the folder named RemoteSystemsTempFiles in your workspace

Answer (score 4):

JSR-109 Web Services is not a project. Its an implementation standard that ensures that your Web Service maintains the Standards and it (your Service) interoperate with other service there is..

Follow the link for more details.

[Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcjsr109.html)

and the following link has a work around on removing the same.

[uncheck JSR-109 Web Services](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/490037/)
[really uncheck JSR-109 Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777590/how-to-remove-jax-ws-web-services-node-in-eclipse-project-explorer)